# Better way to initialize different cell types inside an if statement

Tags: ios, swift

In my code, a `cell` will be of one type if it is in the first `tableView` section, and another if it is not.

```
var cell = UITableViewCell()

if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UpcomingWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyWorkoutsTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = workout.trainer.name
    cell.dateLabel.text = workout.getDateString()
    cell.timeLabel.text = workout.getTimeString()
    cell.trainerImage.image = workout.image
} else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PastWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PastWorkoutTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = workout.trainer.name
    cell.dateLabel.text = workout.getDateString()
    cell.timeLabel.text = workout.getTimeString()
    cell.trainerImage.image = workout.image
    cell.ratingControl.rating = workout.rating // Exclusive to PastWorkoutCell
}
```

Is there a better way to write this? Can I somehow get rid of the initial declaration as a `UITableViewCell` and shorten my code by a line?

Also, MyWorkoutsTableViewCell and PastWorkoutCell have almost all their properties in common. Can I avoid repeating code in each of the branches of the if statement to set all of them? Right now cell is a `UITableViewCell` that doesn't have any properties so I can't seem to do it outside the two branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you try this

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UpcomingWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyWorkoutsTableViewCell
if indexPath.section != 0 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PastWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PastWorkoutTableViewCell
    cell.ratingControl.rating = workout.rating
}
cell.nameLabel.text = workout.trainer.name
cell.dateLabel.text = workout.getDateString()
cell.timeLabel.text = workout.getTimeString()
cell.trainerImage.image = workout.image
```

Comment: This worked in combination with making 'PastWorkoutTableViewCell' inherit from 'MyWorkoutsTableViewCell', since it has all of 'MyWorkoutsTableViewCell''s properties. Thanks.

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes for some reason.

Comment: @yesthisisjoe be sure to include `cell.ratingControl.rating = workout.rating` in the `PastWorkoutCell`, you should be able to include it in the `if` statement

Comment: Edited the answer for rating.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that's unpleasant about your code is that the `cell` declared in the first line is immediately replaced by the *real* cell. To avoid that, use a define-and-call function:

```
let cell : UITableViewCell = {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = // ...
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = // ...
        return cell
    }
}()
```

The duplication can be avoided through a common (abstract) superclass.

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    // declare nameLabel, dateLabel, timeLabel etc.
}
class MyWorkoutsTableViewCell: MyCell {}
class PastWorkoutCell: MyCell {}
```

Now we can restructure like this:

```
let cell : MyCell = {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = // ...
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = // ...
        return cell
    }
}()
// configure MyCell once, here, and return it
```

Answer (score 0):

var cell = UITableViewCell()

```
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UpcomingWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyWorkoutsTableViewCell

    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PastWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PastWorkoutTableViewCell

    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = workout.trainer.name
    cell.dateLabel.text = workout.getDateString()
    cell.timeLabel.text = workout.getTimeString()
    cell.trainerImage.image = workout.image
```

Comment: This doesn't work because UITableViewCell doesn't have the properties nameLabel, dateLabel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nirav's answer is good except for a bit changes

`var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UpcomingWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyWorkoutsTableViewCell
if indexPath.section != 0 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PastWorkoutCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PastWorkoutTableViewCell
    cell.ratingControl.rating = workout.rating
}`

`cell.nameLabel.text = workout.trainer.name
cell.dateLabel.text = workout.getDateString()
cell.timeLabel.text = workout.getTimeString()`